# Archiving fails

Tags: 2011, archival

I am trying to implement archiving for SDL Tridion. Archival fails with the below exception. I am not able to identify the root cause. Any help would be appreciated.

```
2014-02-03 00:00:15,171 ERROR PipelineManager - Unable to execute pipeline archiving-pipeline
2014-02-03 00:00:15,171 ERROR DeploymentPipelineModule - Error executing deployment pipeline group.
com.tridion.pipeline.PipelineException: com.tridion.pipeline.PipelineException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.tridion.archiving.retrieval.RetrievalException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at com.tridion.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.java:145) ~[cd_archivemanager.jar:na]
at com.tridion.pipeline.PipelineManager.executePipeline(PipelineManager.java:462) ~[cd_archivemanager.jar:na]
at com.tridion.archiving.modules.DeploymentPipelineModule.process(DeploymentPipelineModule.java:110) ~[cd_archivemanager.jar:na]
at com.tridion.archiving.processors.TransactionalProcessor.process(TransactionalProcessor.java:51) [cd_archivemanager.jar:na]
at com.tridion.deployer.workers.ProcessorWorker.doWork(ProcessorWorker.java:74) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
at com.tridion.deployer.phases.CommitPhase.onSuccess(CommitPhase.java:112) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runSafeEvent(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:228) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:98) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:61) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:80) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:176) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_33]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_33]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_33]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_33]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_33]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_33]
Caused by: com.tridion.pipeline.PipelineException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.tridion.archiving.retrieval.RetrievalException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at com.tridion.pipeline.steps.UrlCaptureStep.process(UrlCaptureStep.java:216) ~[cd_archivemanager.jar:na]
at com.tridion.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.java:140) ~[cd_archivemanager.jar:na]
... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.tridion.archiving.retrieval.RetrievalException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_33]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_33]
at com.tridion.pipeline.steps.UrlCaptureStep.process(UrlCaptureStep.java:210) ~[cd_archivemanager.jar:na]
... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.tridion.archiving.retrieval.RetrievalException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at com.tridion.archiving.http.HttpCapture.capture(HttpCapture.java:314) ~[cd_archivemanager.jar:na]
at com.tridion.archiving.retrieval.ResponsePackageBuilder.call(ResponsePackageBuilder.java:220) ~[cd_archivemanager.jar:na]
at com.tridion.archiving.retrieval.ResponsePackageBuilder.call(ResponsePackageBuilder.java:247) ~[cd_archivemanager.jar:na]
at com.tridion.archiving.retrieval.ResponsePackageBuilder.call(ResponsePackageBuilder.java:51) ~[cd_archivemanager.jar:na]
... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6]
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6]
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6]
at com.tridion.util.ssl.RelaxedSSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(RelaxedSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:153) ~[cd_archivemanager.jar:na]
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707) ~[commons-httpclient.jar:na]
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387) ~[commons-httpclient.jar:na]
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171) ~[commons-httpclient.jar:na]
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397) ~[commons-httpclient.jar:na]
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323) ~[commons-httpclient.jar:na]
at com.tridion.archiving.http.HttpCapture.capture(HttpCapture.java:221) ~[cd_archivemanager.jar:na]
... 8 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly is the issue, but it is related to your network and/or configuration.

The root cause here is a connection time-out:

`com.tridion.archiving.retrieval.RetrievalException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect`

So possibly your database information is misconfigured? Review your configuration.

**EDIT** Eric's answer is likely to be the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you cannot crawl the content that was deployed in your delivery instance.

```
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_33]
at com.tridion.pipeline.steps.UrlCaptureStep.process(UrlCaptureStep.java:210) ~[cd_archivemanager.jar:na]
... 17 common frames omitted
```

Archive Manager utilizes `Apache HttpClient` in order to crawl the content that was deployed and archive it in the Archive database.

Check if you have Firewall issues or if you Web site is accessible for Archive Manager.